# How do I check if a form element (input or button, etc) is disabled by itself or a parent fieldset in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, fieldset, disabled-input

According to [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/form-control-infrastructure.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute):

> A form control is disabled if any of the following are true:
>
> - the element is a button, input, select, textarea, or form-associated custom element, and the disabled attribute is specified on this
>   element (regardless of its value); or
> - the element is a descendant of a fieldset element whose disabled attribute is specified, and is not a descendant of that fieldset
>   element's first legend element child, if any.

The element itself if not disabled, the `disabled` property is still `false`. How do I determine if an element is disabled by its parent?

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#txt").disabled)
console.log(document.querySelector("#btn").disabled)
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <input id="txt" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset disabled>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Button</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside moving up the DOM tree to find a disabled `fieldset`, I found out CSS `:disabled` selector works as well:

```js
const txts = [1,2,3].map(q => document.querySelector("#txt" + q));

for (const t of txts) {
  console.log('t.matches(:disabled):', t.matches(":disabled"));
}

function isDisabled(el) {
  if (el.disabled) { return true; }

  while (el = el.parentElement) {
    if (el instanceof HTMLFieldSetElement && el.disabled) { return true; }
  }
  
  return false;
}

for (const t of txts) {
  console.log('isDisabled(t):', isDisabled(t));
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <input id="txt1" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input id="txt2" disabled />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input id="txt3" />
</fieldset>
```